# Scott-Potter reflection?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

I'll quote this from the Wikipedia on [Scott-Potter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%E2%80%93Potter_set_theory#Further_existence_premises) set theory:

> **Reflection:** Let $\Phi$ denote a first-order formula in which any number of free variables are present. Let $\Phi^{(V)}$ denote $\Phi$ with these free variables all quantified, with the quantified variables restricted to the level $V$. Then: $\exists V [\Phi \to \Phi^{(V)}]$

What does it mean to say that all the **free** variables of $\Phi$ are quantified in $\Phi^{(V)}$? Does it mean that we have $(\bigwedge \exists x_i \in V: x_i=v_i)$ as a subformula of $\Phi^{(V)}$, where $\vec{v}$ is the string of all free variables of $\Phi$?